# Query on usage of this variable in Recursion

Tags: java, recursion

After calling method,

```
node.nth(5)
```

in below code,

```
public class List_Node {
    int item;
    List_Node next;
    public List_Node() {
        this.item = 0;
        this.next = null;
    }
    public List_Node(int item, List_Node next) {
        this.item = item;
        this.next = next;
    }
    public List_Node(int item) {
        this(item, null);
    }
    public void insertAfter(int item) {
        this.next = new List_Node(item, this.next);
    }
    public List_Node nth(int position) {
        if (position == 1) {
            return this;
        } else if((position < 1) || (this.next == null)) {
        /* error checking */
            return null;
        } else {
            return this.next.nth(position - 1);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List_Node node = new List_Node(0);
        List_Node temp = node;
        for (int item = 1; item < 5; item++) {
            temp.insertAfter(item);
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        System.out.println(node.nth(5).item);
    }
}
```

Below is the stack frame that I can imagine for `nth()` method after 4 recursive calls.

[image]

My question:

As per the above diagram, Assuming the instance of being in activation record `S5` with value of `pos` as `1`, I would like to understand, What happens, when java executes `return this`?
Does java assign the value of `this` in `S5` as value of `this` in `S4`? Because there is no assignment statement (as such) in `else{}` block of `nth()` method.

Note: Please ignore Java coding style, as am new learner.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each time you call `this.next.nth()`, you are calling `nth()` method on a completely different object. Your `this` will refer to that new object (in previous stack it was `next`). Its not a pure recursion. Just think as if you are calling different method on some different object.

So when `position=1` the `this` would refer to `S5`.

**UPDATE**
Lets say your List_Nodes are chained like this 
10->20->30->40->50

Whenever you call `node.nth(5)` from main,

```
Stack 1: position 5, this points to 10 (you are calling this.next.nth(4); means 20.nth())
    Stack 2: position 4, this points to 20 (calling this.next.nth(3); = 30.nth())
        Stack 3: position 3, this points to 30 (calling this.next.nth(2) = 40.nth())
            Stack 4: position 2, this points to 40 (calling this.next.nth(1) = 50.nth())
                Stack 5: position 1, this points to 50 (returning this; this here is 50)
                returns 50
            returns 50 (not going back into if, so return value remains same)
        returns 50
    returns 50
returns 50
```

The same this is depicted in a picture while discussing on chat. Adding it here, to benefit future reader.
[image]

**Another UPDATE**

```
No assignment variable in else as such
```

You can write this like

```
List_Node temp = this.next.nth(position-1);
return temp;
```

In general, we need to separate `List` and `Node` classes, your `List` should have an `head` and your `Node` will have `item` and `next` pointer. Just like the `LinkedList` in java. Then the `nth()` method will be in `List` class and it just iterates through it until you reach the `nth` element.

Comment: I did not get your answer. 1) I would like to ignore seperating node and list class until next lecture video. 2)Did i picturise the stack frame correctly? I mean, Does `this` variable(pointing to different objts) exist in all 5 entries of stack frame? 3) I did not get the answer for the question `what happens on java executing 'return this'`

Comment: Your stack frame is correct, you did a great job in picturing it. I tried to explain it little more. Please see if you get it.

Comment: stack4 pos=2 and stack5 pos=1, looks like copypaste error.--- when you say `returns 50` it is pretty vague. when java executes `return this(referring object 50)` in S5 record, stack frame turns back. Amidst that wind-up, How `this` variables of s4/s3/s2/s1 is changed? I need to understand. Becasue i initially entered into nth() methos with `this` variable of S1 record

Comment: Corrected the typo, `this` has a very limited scope here, `return this` means return the current instance's reference (which is a reference to List_Node with item 50). once it returns from `Stack 5` to `Stack 4`, `Stack 4` actually gets a reference of the List_Node (with item 50) and it will also poped out and returns the same reference to `Stack 3` and so on.

Comment: After first return(`pos=1`), `this` variable of S4 will point to object having value 4 and lose the reference to object having value 3, After second return(`pos=2`) `this` variable of S3 points to 4 and lose the reference to object having value 2.... so on?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61017/discussion-between-rp-and-overexchange).