# Why do i separate List and Node class?

Tags: java, list

Let me ask this question taking Java code mentioned in the query [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755446/query-on-usage-of-this-variable-in-recursion).

In the same query [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755446/query-on-usage-of-this-variable-in-recursion), a supplementary answer says: "`In general, we need to separate List and Node classes, your List should have an head and your Node will have item and next pointer.`"

In addition, my class lecture says, there are two reasons for separating List and Node class.

*Reason 1:*
Assume user X and user Y are pointing to the first `List_Node` in that list

[image]

After adding soap item by user X in the shopping list, below is the situation,

[image]

So, User Y is inconsistent with this situation.

*Reason 2:*

Handling empty list.
user X pointing to an empty list, that mean X is null.

```
X.nth(1); //Null pointer exception
```

My question:

Reason_1 could have been handled by inserting new node after last node. Reason_2 could have been handled, as part of error check in the code.
So, Why exactly we need to separate Node and List class?

Note: Java code has `item` of type `int`instead of type `Object` that can accommodate strings. I did not want to change this code again.

Comment: A *list of things* and a *thing in a list* are conceptually very different concepts and so it makes sens to use different classes to represent them.  The other reasons are more technical and should not concern you that much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Reason_1 could have been handled by inserting new node after last node.

But that is changing the problem.  Lists are ordered.  Adding an element before an existing element or after an existing element are different operations.  The data structure must be able to handle both operations, otherwise it is not a proper list.

> Reason_2 could have been handled, as part of error check in the code.

That wouldn't work.  The code of your list abstraction *can't* handle the NPE.  If you attempt to call `x.nth(1)` and `x` is `null`, the exception is thrown *before* you get into any of the code that implements the list.  Therefore, the (hypothetical) error handling in the list code cannot be executed.  (Java exception handling doesn't work like that ...)

And as you *correctly* point out in your comment, forcing code that uses a list to handle empty lists as a special case would be bad list API design.

In short, both of the reasons stated are valid.  (IMO)

Comment: Yes stephen, "the code" means the code of list abstraction. Obviously error check can't be done in driver code that uses List, Because this would be a bad design of List abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some very good reasons:

- Separate implementation from interface. Perhaps in the future someone will find a new perfectly good implementation of your life involving a row of carrier pigeons moving elements around. Should your client code have to update everything with methods `flapWings` and `rewardPigeon` instead of manipulating nodes? No! (More realistically, Java offers `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` IIRC).
- It makes more sense. `list.reverse()` makes sense. `node.reverse()`... what? Does this change every other node recursively or not?
- Speaking of that `reverse` method, if you implement it right now you can implement it in O(N). You know if you have an `int orientation;` that is 1 or -1, you can implement it in O(1)? But all subsequent operations need to use that bit, so it's a meta-node operation, not a node operation.
- Empty lists are possible. Empty nodes don't make sense. This is your (2). Imagine this: I am a client of your software. You have list == node. A rival vendor offers separation. You say "oh it works fine just add an error check in your code." Your rival does not. Who do I buy from? This is a thought experiment meant to convince you these really *are* different, and the former does have a defect.

Comment: I am yet to learn idea about interface & implementation. Probably, try to understand your answer at right time.